# Developing for Android and IOS with C

Tags: android, ios, mobile, embedded

Is it possible to develop apps for Android and IOS using pure ANSI C?
How can I do that? Is there any tutorial that explain how can I do this?

Is it possible to write generic cross-platform programas in C, which could run in Android and IOS? I know that there are some alternatives for cross-platform development. However, they have some limitations regarding the access to the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ are both available on both platforms. However, there isn't really a terminal, or command line tools, on iOS. You have to create an app using native iOS frameworks. You could create a wrapper for both platforms that presented a common interface and then write to that on both platforms. There are also cross-platform frameworks, although I haven't used any of them, just read about them.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use C/C++ for application development in Android.

Download the Android NDK from developer.android.com

Extract the and generate the toolchain using the shell script in **./build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh** by passing the required parameters

Make sure you have installed **Cygwin/MinGW** before you run the script in Windows.

After generating the toolchain,set your environment variable *PATH* to **./arm-linux-androideabi-x.x/bin**

Create a small C program and try compiling as shown in the image

[C program compilation using Android NDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvDgm.png)

Copy the executable file to your phone.Install Terminal Emulator on your phone from PlayStore

Do as shown in the image on your phone

[Hello World Program in Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKBIZ.png)